# Cannot set a different database directory for mysql ( Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I am attempting to relocate the database directory for my mysql installation to a newly install ssd.

Configuration:

`Ubuntu 16.04
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

I modified `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to include a new database dir:

```
datadir = /mnt/5abeaa6e-7536-4213-bb3e-97aa9a81be16/mysql
```

Now in running `sudo service mysql start` it brings up a permissions error:

```
mysqld[9002]: mysqld: Can't change dir to '/mnt/5abeaa6e-7536-4213-bb3e-97aa9a81be16/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

I have run both recursive chmod and chown commands on the new directory to match it up and the stat readout now shows as follows:

```
$ stat /var/lib/mysql
  File: '/var/lib/mysql'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 812h/2066d  Inode: 13381090    Links: 8
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (  127/   mysql)   Gid: (  134/   mysql)
Access: 2016-06-23 09:42:37.687378790 -0700
Modify: 2016-06-23 09:46:04.679025933 -0700
Change: 2016-06-23 09:46:04.679025933 -0700
 Birth: -

$ stat /mnt/5abeaa6e-7536-4213-bb3e-97aa9a81be16/mysql
  File: '/mnt/5abeaa6e-7536-4213-bb3e-97aa9a81be16/mysql'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 820h/2080d  Inode: 3276801     Links: 3
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (  127/   mysql)   Gid: (  134/   mysql)
Access: 2016-06-23 09:45:16.190998487 -0700
Modify: 2016-06-22 18:37:37.707197266 -0700
Change: 2016-06-23 09:45:16.190998487 -0700
 Birth: -
```

I also modified `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` to

```
# Allow data dir access
#  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
#  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
/mnt/5abeaa6e-7536-4213-bb3e-97aa9a81be16/mysql/ r,
/mnt/5abeaa6e-7536-4213-bb3e-97aa9a81be16/mysql/** rwk,
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/05/move-mysql-directory/), you need to edit some configuration and run a few commands to complete the setup.

Add the following to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`:

```
/NEWSQLPATH/ r,
/NEWSQLPATH/** rwk,
```

Then run:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

You can also add this to `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`:

```
alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /newpath/,
```

(**The commas at the ends of the lines are important.**)